# how to getItmes from sqlite data base calling the method in any other class instead of appDelegate in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I have getQuestions method in QuestionData like the following signature i want that 
user may call this function in other class except appDelagate how to call this there becuase getDBPath is declared in appDelegate..

how to access this method in any other class

```
[QuestionData getQuestions:[self getDBPath]];

+ (void)getQuestions:(NSString*)dbPath{
```